# Parse words from GET request

Tags: arduino

I have a get request which looks like this :

```
GET /mydataA:mydataB HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.4.1
Accept: */*
Accept-aneeAop
n1kD0
```

I would like to get only the data between the `GET/` and  `HTTP/1.1` , which in this case is  `mydataA:mydataB` .
This respond is a char array in the size of 500. what i do now to get the data is :

```
     //Wificontent has the respond
     String parseGET=Wificontent;
     int ind1 = parseGET.indexOf('GET /');
     int ind2 = parseGET.indexOf('HTTP/1.1');
     Serial.println(parseGET.substring(ind1+1, ind2-8));
```

Which result in a strange inconsistent results, of part of the data .

How would i get that data in a safe way ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, for anyone who needs it :

```
             String parseGET=Wificontent;
             String from="GET /";
             String to="HTTP";
             int ind1 = parseGET.indexOf(from);
             int ind2 = parseGET.indexOf(to);
             Serial.println(parseGET.substring(ind1+from.length(), ind2-1));
```